# Why i cant select statement with is null condition in function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i tried following plsql-function and wondered that it isnt working:

```
function fct_mytable_has_value(p_id IN mytable.Id%Type) return boolean is
begin

return (select mt.id from mytable mt where mt.id = p_id) IS NULL;

end;
```

someone can explain why this ends up in a compilation error? And maybe a smart solution?

Comment: _"it isnt working"_ Compilation error? Execution error? Not producing what's expected?

Comment: `why this doesnt work?` Because it's semantically incorrect. Declare a variable, select into that variable, then do the null checking. Bear in mind that the usage of this function won't go beyond PL/SQL. Put it simply, because it returns a value of `boolean` data type, you cannot use it in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather meaningless to test for a cursor being NULL.

Probably you are looking for a simple COUNT. Something *like* that:

```
select COUNT(*) into my_int_var  from mytable mt where mt.id = p_id;
return my_int_var;
```